# Workaround document.write function

Tags: javascript, ads, document.write

I'm trying to find a way to ease my users life (by avoiding render blocking) by removing all document.write() that could be made by ads scripts.

The orignal works like this :

```
var ad_tmstp=Math.round(Math.random()*10000000000),
sas_masterflag=1;

function adscript(ad_pageid,ad_formatid,ad_target)
{
 var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
 var currentScript = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];

 if (ad_masterflag==1) {ad_masterflag=0;ad_master='M';} else {ad_master='S';};

document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://www.ads.com/call/pubj/' + ad_pageid + '/' + ad_formatid + '/' + ad_master + '/' + ad_tmstp + '/' + escape(ad_target) + '?"></scr'+'ipt>');
}
```

This is the master ads function, used to generate unique ad url, document.write() it to the DOM, and make he response execute.

The call to this master function is made in site, where ad needs to be inserted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ad_pageid='16645/120305'; 
  ad_formatid=7366;     
  ad_target='';         
  adscript(ad_pageid,ad_formatid,ad_target);
</script>
```

When page loads, master script is executed, causing document.write() to happen. Dynamic script is loaded, and is itself executed and ends with a nasty

```
  [...]Ad innerCode creation[...]
  if(typeof(ad_ajax)!='undefined'&&ad_ajax)  
  {ad_appendToContainer(1234,innerCode);}else{document.write(innerCode);}
```

Nasty enough to be seriously watched...

So, what i've been trying so far :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.defer= "true";
  script.src  = 'http://www.ads.com/call/pubj/' + ad_pageid + '/' + ad_formatid + '/' + ad_master + '/' + ad_tmstp + '/' + escape(ad_target) + '?';
  currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore( script, currentScript.nextSibling );
```

HTML rendering is perfect : #1 creates #2.
But, for some reason, #2, containing the final document.write() wich should generate ad content, doesn't execute.

What could I possibly be missing ? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't fully understand. You append the new script element correctly (and can verify that its src attribute is the correct one? What happens if you load its src attribute to a new window?).  But while the correct script is appended, the code doesnot execute? No errors thrown?

Comment: That's exactly what happens. The src attribute in a new window displays the javavascript source code generated from the ad provider, and meant to generate and insert the ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate all `document.write()` calls, just do this:

```
document.write = function() {};
```

and each `document.write()` call won't do anything :)

(maybe i just misunderstood you because it's this simple ;))

Comment: That's not it. I'm not trying to override document.write(), but to replace with a more block less browser rendering technique.

Comment: well then just replace it with a function doing what you want ;)

Comment: No, replace the document.write function with the thing you want :)